# SQL group by and sum based on distinct value in other column (sum once if value in other column is duplicated)

Tags: sql, group-by, sum, teradata, distinct

I need help with a group-by query. My table looks like this:

```sql
CREATE MULTISET TABLE MY_TABLE (PERSON CHAR(1), ITEM CHAR(1), COST INT);
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE VALUES ('A', '1', 5);
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE VALUES ('A', '1', 5);
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE VALUES ('A', '2', 1);
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE VALUES ('B', '3', 0);
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE VALUES ('B', '4', 10);
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE VALUES ('B', '4', 10);
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE VALUES ('C', '5', 1);
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE VALUES ('C', '5', 1);
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE VALUES ('C', '5', 1);
```

```
+--------+------+------+
| PERSON | ITEM | COST |
+--------+------+------+
| A      | 1    |    5 |
| A      | 1    |    5 |
| A      | 2    |    1 |
| B      | 3    |    0 |
| B      | 4    |   10 |
| B      | 4    |   10 |
| C      | 5    |    1 |
| C      | 5    |    1 |
| C      | 5    |    1 |
+--------+------+------+
```

I need to group items and costs by person, but in different ways. For each person, I need the number of unique items they have. Ex: Person `A` has two distinct items, item 1 and item 2. I can get this with `COUNT(DISTINCT ITEM)`.

Then for each person, I need to sum the cost but only **once per distinct item** (for duplicate items, the cost is always the same). Ex: Person `A` has item 1 for $5, item 1 for $5, and item 2 for $1. Since this person has item 1 twice, I count the $5 once, and then add the $1 from item 2 for a total of $6. The output should look like this:

```
+--------+---------------------+------------------------+
| PERSON | ITEM_DISTINCT_COUNT | COST_DISTINCT_ITEM_SUM |
+--------+---------------------+------------------------+
| A      |                   2 |                      6 |
| B      |                   2 |                     10 |
| C      |                   1 |                      1 |
+--------+---------------------+------------------------+
```

Is there an easy way to do this that performs good on a lot of rows?

```sql
SELECT PERSON
  ,COUNT(DISTINCT ITEM) ITEM_DISTINCT_COUNT
  -- help with COST_DISTINCT_ITEM_SUM
FROM MY_TABLE
GROUP BY PERSON
```

Comment: Is your target system really Teradata? TD doesn't support this multi-VALUES syntax.

Comment: @dnoeth it is Teradata. I updated that piece of code, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can make a subquery which gets the distinct values of `item` and `cost` for each person, and then aggregate over that:

```
SELECT PERSON, 
       COUNT(ITEM) AS ITEM_DISTINCT_COUNT,
       SUM(COST) AS COST_DISTINCT_ITEM_SUM 
FROM (
  SELECT DISTINCT PERSON, ITEM, COST
  FROM MY_TABLE
) M
GROUP BY PERSON
```

Output:

```
PERSON  ITEM_DISTINCT_COUNT     COST_DISTINCT_ITEM_SUM
A       2                       6
B       2                       10
C       1                       1
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/rXJ6xz2R2SKSP2zqToXnJD/0)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend a two levels of aggregation:

```
select person, count(*) as num_items, sum(cost)
from (select person, item, avg(cost) as cost
      from my_table t
      group by person, item
     ) t
group by person;
```

Comment: Gordon, is there an easy way to create tables for such posts without writing sql queries? I'd like a spreadsheet like tool which lets you enter data and convert it into SQL to create table. That way, I can type less.

Comment: @ErranMorad . . . The insert statement that you have is the most useful for other -- well, an actual SQL or DB Fiddle would be a little more useful.

Comment: @ErranMorad both [SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com) and [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com) have text to DDL tools that do what you want.